# redux action creator sets value only from second time

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

I have an action-creator which sends get-request and sets a user:

```
export const login = (email: string, password: string) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => {
        try {
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER})
            const response = await axios.get<IUser>('http://localhost:8080/users/login', {
                params: {
                    email,
                    password
                }
            })
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, payload: response.data})
        }catch (e) {
            dispatch({
                type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USER_ERROR,
                payload: 'Произошла ошибка при загрузке пользователя'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And in this method i use this action-creator

```
    const logIn = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        login(email.value, password.value)

        console.log(user)
    }
```

But when i put on the button first, I get `null` in logs, when i put second time, i get my object:

```
{id: 1, name: 'Matvey', email: 'matvey@gmail.com', phone: '375255198474', password: 'matvey', …}
```

But if i make button which will show me user, and click first time to log in, i get in logs null, but when i click to the button to show user, i get my user. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. At the time `logIn` is called, the variable `user` that is binded is null, what your action is going to update is the state in your store and not the local variable
2. Your `login` action is asynchronous so the user won't be available right after the call to `login`

Comment: How can i fix it? user is object received from useSelect